# Better method to using system() and external commands ip/iw/dhcpcd

Tags: c, linux, awk

I wrote simple wlan manager tool. It uses system() to run iproute2/iw/wpa_supplicant/dhcpcd to connect to access points. Now i would like to improve it to better method than runnning external commands. Some people say you should never use system() as there is always better way in C.

I explored wicd and seems like it works purely by executing and parsing external commands. NetworkManager is more complicated and seems to use some other methods. I have understood it is best done with external libraries. If this is the case i would like to know which libraries i should look for. As a side note it would be nice to hear if i have made poor choises in the code design.

ccwm.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

char **global_argv;

void usage() {
    printf("Usage: %s [options] -o/-a/-w/-W\n\n", global_argv[0]);

    puts("-h              Show help\n");

    puts("-i [interface]  Set interface (default: wlan0)");
    puts("-e [ssid]       Set SSID");
    puts("-f [freq]       Set frequency");
    puts("-k [key]        Set key/passphrase\n");

    puts("-s              Scan access points");
    puts("-S              Scan access points verbosely");
    puts("-I              Show interface info\n");

    puts("-o              Connect to ESS access point");
    puts("-a              Connect to IBSS access point");
    puts("-w              Connect to WEP encrypted access point");
    puts("-W              Connect to WPA encrypted access point");
}

void ifup(char *ifname) {
    char *cmdline = "";
    cmdline = malloc(36);
    size_t s1 = strlen(ifname);
    snprintf(cmdline, s1+16, "ip link set %s up", ifname);
    system(cmdline);
    free(cmdline);
}

void scan(char *ifname, int type) {
    char *cmdline = "";
    cmdline = malloc(33);
    size_t s1 = strlen(ifname);

    if (type == 0) {
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+31, "iw dev %s scan | awk -f scan.awk", ifname);
        system(cmdline);
    }
    else {
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+13, "iw dev %s scan", ifname);
        system(cmdline);
    }

    free(cmdline);
}

void info(char *ifname) {
    char *cmdline = "";
    cmdline = malloc(43);
    size_t s1 = strlen(ifname);
    snprintf(cmdline, s1+13, "iw dev %s info", ifname);
    system(cmdline);
    snprintf(cmdline, s1+13, "iw dev %s link", ifname);
    system(cmdline);
    snprintf(cmdline, s1+23, "iw dev %s get power_save", ifname);
    system(cmdline);
    free(cmdline);
}

void connect(char *ifname, char *essid, char *freq, char *key, int type) {
    system("killall dhcpcd 2> /dev/null");
    char *cmdline = "";
    cmdline = malloc(100);
    size_t s1 = strlen(ifname);
    size_t s2 = strlen(essid);
    size_t s3 = strlen(freq);
    size_t s4 = strlen(key);

    if (type < 3) {
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+25, "iw dev %s set type managed", ifname);
        system(cmdline);
    }
    else {
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+22, "iw dev %s set type ibss", ifname);
        system(cmdline);
    }

    if (type == 0) {
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+s2+20, "iw dev %s connect -w %s", ifname, essid);
        system(cmdline);
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+8, "dhcpcd %s", ifname);
        system(cmdline);
    }
    else if (type == 1) {
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+s2+s4+26, "iw dev %s connect -w %s keys %s", ifname, essid, key);
        system(cmdline);
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+8, "dhcpcd %s", ifname);
        system(cmdline);
    }
    else if (type == 2) {
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+s2+s4+45, "wpa_supplicant -B -i %s -c <(wpa_passphrase %s %s)",
                                    ifname, essid, key);
        system(cmdline);
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+8, "dhcpcd %s", ifname);
        system(cmdline);
    }
    else {
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+s2+s3+20, "iw dev %s ibss join %s %s", ifname, essid, freq);
        system(cmdline);
        snprintf(cmdline, s1+8, "dhcpcd %s", ifname);
        system(cmdline);
    }

    free(cmdline);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    global_argv = argv;
    int opt;
    char *ifname = "wlan0";
    char *essid = "";
    char *freq = "";
    char *key = "";

    uid_t uid=getuid();
    if (uid != 0) {
        puts("\nThis program needs to be run with root privileges!\n");
    }

    if (argc <= 1) {
        usage();
    }

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "IsSowWahi:e:f:k:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'i':
                ifname = optarg;
                break;
            case 'e':
                essid = optarg;
                break;
            case 'f':
                freq = optarg;
                break;
            case 'k':
                key = optarg;
                break;
            case 'I':
                ifup(ifname);
                info(ifname);
                break;
            case 's':
                ifup(ifname);
                scan(ifname, 0);
                break;
            case 'S':
                ifup(ifname);
                scan(ifname, 1);
                break;
            case 'o':
                if (essid[0] == '\0') {
                    printf("You must specify ssid!\n");
                    break;
                }
                ifup(ifname);
                connect(ifname, essid, freq, key, 0);
                break;
            case 'w':
                if (essid[0] == '\0' || key[0] == '\0') {
                    printf("You must specify ssid and key!\n");
                    break;
                }
                ifup(ifname);
                connect(ifname, essid, freq, key, 1);
                break;
            case 'W':
                if (essid[0] == '\0' || key[0] == '\0') {
                    printf("You must specify ssid and passphrase!\n");
                    break;
                }
                ifup(ifname);
                connect(ifname, essid, freq, key, 2);
                break;
            case 'a':
                if (essid[0] == '\0' || freq[0] == '\0') {
                    printf("You must specify ssid and freq!\n");
                    break;
                }
                ifup(ifname);
                connect(ifname, essid, freq, key, 3);
                break;
            case 'h':
            default:
                usage();
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

scan.awk

```
/^BSS / {
    MAC = $2
    wifi[MAC]["enc"] = "Open"
}
$1 == "SSID:" {
    wifi[MAC]["SSID"] = $2
}
$1 == "freq:" {
    wifi[MAC]["freq"] = $2
}
$1 == "signal:" {
    wifi[MAC]["sig"] = $2 " " $3
}
$1 == "capability:" {
    wifi[MAC]["type"] = $2
}
$1 == "WPA:" {
    wifi[MAC]["enc"] = "WPA"
}
$1 == "WEP:" {
    wifi[MAC]["enc"] = "WEP"
}
END {
    for (w in wifi) {
        if ( i++ > 0 ) { printf "\n" }
        printf "SSID: %s\nType: %s\nFrequency: %s\nSignal: %s\nEncryption: %s\n"\
        ,wifi[w]["SSID"],wifi[w]["type"],wifi[w]["freq"],wifi[w]["sig"],wifi[w]["enc"]
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for coolest 3rd question **ever** (that I've seen) from a S.O. poster. Sorry, but you seem to know more about this topic than I do, so I can't comment on code, except that awk script looks like a good design. Keep posting and good luck!

Comment: You could `strace` -or perhaps `ltrace`- the commands `iproute2` etc... and since they are free software, you could even study their source code. Notice that the kernel gives a lot of information thru `/proc/`

Comment: Have a look at [netlink](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356) - i think it will provide part of what you need at least.

Comment: More links: [sample code](http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2009/01/sample-code-to-learn-netlink.html), [helper lib](http://netfilter.org/projects/libmnl/)

Comment: Thanks for help. It seems that the tools use libnl and kernels nl80211 directly. Im trying to study using nl80211 but there is no documentation nor example code. There is only kerneldoc where enum nl80211_commands are listed. I have no idea how to use those commands? I have been trying to study from iw and wpa_supplicant source but its rather complex.